# Como executar funçao do Model na View com codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php-7, codeigniter-3

Estou a usar codeigniter(baseado em PHP e no Model-Control-View). Tenho um controller que carrega um Model e uma View.

**[Controller]**

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['agenda_model'] = $this->load->model('agenda_model');
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        $this->load->view('commons/bootstrap-scripts');
    }
```

**[View]**

```
<body onload="initialize()">
</body>
<script>
   function initialize(){
       console.log(<?php echo $agenda_model->getAgendaDate('05-03-2019'); ?>);
  }
</script>
```

**[Model]**

```
public function getAgendaDate($date){
        echo $date;
        $sql = 'select * from agenda';
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result->num_rows;
    }
```

Quando executo o código acima, tenho o seguinte erro no script.
*ERRO: Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined
    at onload*

**[Simplificação/Debbuging]**
Para simplificar as coisas, decidi fazer um echo em php dentro do javascript.

```
var result = <?php echo "maria"; ?>;
console.log(result);

(index):2698 Uncaught ReferenceError: maria is not defined
```

**[update]** - 02/03/2019

"PHP é executado ao lado do servidor" isso pode explicar porque não consigo executar uma das funções do Model. Existe uma design pattern para executar métodos do model na view?
Contudo isto não explica porque não executa:

```
var result = <?php echo "maria"; ?>;
```

Minha dúvida. Será eficiente com alternativa, fazer HTTP GET/POST?

Answer (score 3):

Para chamar a model em uma view, você pode tentar instanciar o core do Codeigniter na mesma, usando 
`$CI =& get_instance()` e então dando load na model usando `$CI->load->model('suaModel')`. A partir de então pode utilizar o `$CI->suaModel` para chamar métodos dela na view.

Em relação ao erro javascript, isso acontece porque você está printando a string maria dentro de um script, entretanto a saída do php está fora de aspas. Sendo assim, o javasript entende como nome de variável, e não uma string.

Seguindo seu exemplo:

```
var result = <?php echo "maria"; ?>;
```

A saída será:

```
var result = maria;
```

Ou seja, seu script buscará uma variável chamada maria, que é 'undefined' porque não está setada. O correto é colocar a saída do PHP entre aspas do script:

```
var result = '<?php echo "maria"; ?>';
```

Sendo assim, a saída será:

```
var result = 'maria';
```

Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Onde executo as funções para instanciar o core?

Comment: No próprio arquivo onde deseja usá-lo. No seu caso, na view. Lembrando que isso é um pecado no MVC haha

Comment: Também me parece ir contra a ideologia do MVC. Por exemplo se fizer um $_GET('nome') na view, o que significa o argumento 'nome'. Onde espero pelo GET? Tenho que atribuir uma rota?
Foge um pouco ao tópico, mas é uma solução alternativa. No entanto ainda não encontrei documentação clara para GET/POST, pode ajudar-me?

Comment: Considerando que está usando a versão 3.x do CI, você pode ver a documentação que explica sobre get, post e tudo mais relacionado à inputs aqui: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html